# functions.php How to add css/js depending on Template Name?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-style

How to add custom CSS and JS files depending on the Template Name? For example my normal pages will all have a green background color. Now I want that `Blue Template` will have a blue background color done with an extra CSS file. How can I do that?

**Blue.php**

```
<?php
/*
  Template Name: Blue Template
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">
  <h1>This template has an blue background!</h1>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
  function load_theme_files() {
    # Green background - Default Stylesheet, all pages need this one
    wp_enqueue_style('style', esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ).'/style.css');  

    # What I need - This should add blue.css to the header
    if ($currentTemplate == 'Blue Template') {
      wp_enqueue_style('blue', esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ).'/blue.css');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'load_theme_files');
?>
```

This shoud give all normal pages `<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css".` and my Blue Template will have blue.css below my normal style.css.

I tried `if ( is_page_template( 'blue.php' ) ) { # HERE THE BLUE CSS }` but this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_enqueue_style()` before running `get_header()` in your blue.php file.

If you're looking for a way to do that inside your functions.php file, then the `init` hook is a bit too early for `is_page_template()`. Try the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_theme_files' );
function load_my_theme_files() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'blue.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( ... );
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: So the problem was that I used `init` instead of `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Does it matter if I use `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `wp_enqueue_styles`? I would like to call both in the same function (i.e. Both scripts and CSS files)

Comment: There's no action called `wp_enqueue_styles`, you can enqueue both scripts and styles during `wp_enqueue_scripts`, that's what the default themes do too.

Comment: Ah, oké. I thought I read that somewhere. Thanks for help! :)